# show time icon on the extended monitor

Tags: 12.04, system-tray

On my ubuntu 12.04, the system tray icons are only available on one monitor. How can I let the time icon show on the other monitor too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system tray icons are show on primary monitor. To make a monitor primary, we need to edit `~/.config/monitors.xml`.

Find the node corresponding to the monitor you want to be primary, the change

```
<primary>no</primary>
```

to

```
<primary>yes</primary>
```

Log out and log in. The system tray icons will be there.